# Warning in HTML pages run from CDROM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A customer asked me to realize a web app using jQuery to be run from HTML pages inside a CDROM as `file:///index.html`

When I launch the HTML page I always get security warnings from the browser. Is there a way to avoid all those warnings that are annoying for the user?

Comment: What's your programming question?

Comment: @p.campbell what's your help in this answer?

Comment: What warnings come up in which browser?

Comment: this could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400947/running-javascript-in-ie-without-warning-the-webpage-you-are-trying-to-access-w

Comment: when i open the page from IE, i get a security warning that asks the user to accept the execution of scripts

Comment: "How can I stop the software I am writing cause the interpretor to throw warnings in a given environment?" sounds very like like a programming related question to me.

Comment: He's 'realizing' the web app, which doesn't mean anything. The question is poorly written. If it had any details on environment, warning screenshot/text, or anything useful in the breadcrumb sense, it might be worth keeping.

Comment: Very few details given, we don't even know the browser.  I'd presume that if security warnings are given by the browser they are there for a reason and what you're asking for is a hack to trick the browser.

Comment: @p.campbell: I'm guessing that's just an artifact of translation.  "Realizing" could mean "bringing the idea to reality", "making something happen", or more simply... "developing".  No need to be critical of an attempt at translation if the message is still conveyed.

Comment: when i receive such useless and tedious comments i really hate SO.

Answer (score 7):

Presumably "the browser" is "Internet Explorer".

Give the pages [the mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx). (One of the examples given for when to do this is "You are coding pages that will be viewed from a CD.")

Add the following to each page (just after the Doctype):

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```